# Showing that the groups (Q,+) and (Q⁺,*) are not isomorphic

Tags: group-theory, group-isomorphism

The additive group of rational numbers is not isomorphic to the multiplicative group of positive rational numbers.
How should I show this? What structural property does the first group possess that the other does not?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/33607/group-of-positive-rationals-under-multiplication-not-isomorphic-to-group-of-rati

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The additive group has the property that for all $w$ there exists $x$ such that $x+x=w$. The multiplicative group does not have the property that for all $w$ there exists $x$ such that $x\cdot x=w$, since $\sqrt{2}$ is irrational.

**Remark:** So one important structural difference is that the first group is **divisible** (the equation $x+x+\cdots +x=w$ has a solution for every $w$) while the second group is not divisible.